# How to get folder which has the greatest number

Tags: shell, filenames

Say you have a parent directory which contains 4 subdirectories. Each subdirectory contains identical contents. Also each subdirectory name is an integer number, the greater the integer number the newer the directory and it's contents

**Example:**

> parentdir/
>   -> 1/
>   -> 2/
>   -> 6/
>   -> 3/

How do I get the greatest subdirectory as specified in a path such as:

`/user/mosawi/parentdir/${NEWEST}/payload.gzip`

this would evaluate to:
`/user/mosawi/parentdir/6/payload.gzip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers have the same number of digits, the usual sort order should do, so we could just fill an array with the names and take the last element

```
$ mkdir -p parentdir/{1,2,6,3}
$ A=(parentdir/*)              # fill an array with the names
$ echo "${A[-1]}"              # print the last member of the array
parentdir/6
$ echo "${A[-1]##*/}"          # remove everything up to last / 
6
```

But if they have different number of digits, that won't work (order would be `1`, `13`, `2`, ...). So let's find the maximum manually:

```
$ mkdir -p parentdir/{1,2,6,3,13}
$ max=0;                       # assuming they're non-negative integers!
$ for x in parentdir/* ; do 
    n=${x##*/};                # take just the number so that comparisons work 
    [ "$n" -gt "$max" ] && max=$n 
  done
$ echo "$max" 
13
```

The previous is so much easier that it's worth considering creating the names padded to a fixed length with leading zeroes, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

You need the newest directory, right? So stop toying with numbers and let `zsh` do the job:

```
NEWEST=(/user/mosawi/parentdir/*(/om[1]))
NEWESR=${NEWEST}/payload.gzip
```

The trick is use glob qualifiers to sort (**o**) directories (**/**) on modification time (**m**) and get only the first one (**[1]**).

Comment: "So stop toying with numbers and let `zsh` do the job" favorite quote of the day :) I am limited to bash shell unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

`mkdir -p parentdir/{1,2,6,3,13}`

just `ls`, without sorting:

```
ls parentdir/
1  13  2  3  6
```

now sort:

```
ls parentdir/ -v
1  2  3  6  13
```

Now sorting and take the last:

```
ls parentdir/ -v | tail -n1
13
```

Pros: no loops, one-liner

Contra: invoke external command

Comment: This is really cleaver, I like it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the directory names sort properly (i.e. they contain the same number of digits and there are no non-numerical names in the directory):

```
newest="$(printf '%s\n' /user/mosawi/parentdir/* | tail -n 1)"
```

The file will be `"$newest/payload.gzip"`.

Another trick is to create a symbolic link to the latest directory whenever a new directory is created:

```
mkdir "parentdir/$i" && ln -sf "parentdir/$i" parentdir/latest
```

It is then easy to access `parentdir/latest/payload.gzip`.